# How to reload a collectionview when navigating back?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, lifecycle

I use :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    self.recordView.reloadData()

}
```

But the `recordView` is nil and the app crashes when I navigate back to the previous ViewController.

How to fix this problem? Or is there any workaround method?

Comment: is `recordView` your tableView?

Comment: what does the crash say?

Comment: @rounak `Unexpectedly found nil when unwrap an optional`, say, the recordView is nil.

Comment: @FongTinyik Is `recordView` your tableView?

Comment: @trevorj It's a UICollectionView, indeed.

Comment: @FongTinyik The question says tableView and so do your tags.

Comment: @trevorj Oops my bad. But aren't they functioning in the same way?

Comment: @FongTinyik They're very similar, but I wanted to make sure we're talking about the right thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

Have you set the UICollectionView's `dataSource` and `delegate` properties?

Have you implemented `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`?

How are you accessing your UICollectionView? Did you set up an `@IBOutlet`? Is it a Collection View Controller? Or did you do it all in code? You've got to make sure the collection view is there **before** `viewWillAppear()` is called.

I would start by checking these things.

Comment: 1. Yes I've set.. 2. Yes I've implemented. 3 I created it in storyboard and made it an IBOutelet. 4. It's a UIViewController. 5. The recordView functions correctly but when I try to access it in viewWillAppear it crashes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FongTinyik Is this all in a navigation controller? When you say "navigating back", do you mean tapping the "Back" button that appears in the navigation controller's navigation bar on the top left?

Comment: Yes. The weird thing is even when I call `recordView.reloadData()` in UIViewController itself via a button it's still nil and crashes. But the recordView IS showing contents correctly.

Comment: @FongTinyik Try re-establishing the outlet: right-click on the collection view in interface builder, click the 'x' in the Outlets section to break the connection, then control-drag from the collection view to your `@IBOutlet` in your code. Maybe there's a bad connection there. If that doesn't work I think we'll need to see more of your code.

Comment: Aha you got it ! The connection is broken. Really a foolish mistake ! Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

@synthesize your tableview and use like this

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(true)

    recordView.reloadData()

}
```

May be helpfull...